# Keycloak authentication on socket io

Tags: node.js, authentication, socket.io, keycloak

I am trying to find out how to authenticate a socket io connection with keycloak. I have used successfully  keycloak.protect() function as a middle ware in express, but I am at loss when it comes to socket io.
I want something similar to this.

```
app.get("/examples",keycloak.protect(), function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../production/examples.html'));
});
```

For example to this :

```
io.on('connection', keycloak.protect(), function(socket){

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
    ...
    io.emit('terminal',user_name);

});
```

Comment: Socket.io is not an http endpoint. The keycloak middleware for node, is applied to http requests. Why do you want to apply authentication to a socket.io connection?

Comment: I think  Keycloak doesn't supports socket connection but HTTP.

Comment: has anyone found a way out for socket implementation with keycloak