# Use Keycloak to secure socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Continuing the question on [Keycloak authentication on socket io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50001685/keycloak-authentication-on-socket-io) , how to apply keycloak.protect() or keycloak.chesk-sso() for socket.io to secure only the socket part only instead of securing the entire page? Like to enable guest mode. Is using keycloak for only socket a bad idea?